# Run function both as constexpr and without constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr

i have a class that generates a pseudorandom number.

i need to run the pseudorandom number generator function both in a constexpr function (i need it to generate it at compile-time) and during run-time

it works perfectly, but i am wondering if there's some way to do the following:

i want a single function that generates the number and that i can tell wether i want it at compile or run time. that is because if i write 2 different ones, i have to rewrite the same code twice and it makes it slightly less intuitive to use

i have thought about using define like this:

```
#ifdef COMPILETIME
int constexpr function();
#else
int function();
#endif
```

but all of the defines are global. i cant just undefine and redefine them whenever I want troughout the code

is there some way i can achieve this or am i forever doomed to use 2 separate functions?

Comment: `constexpr` functions can be called both at compile time, and at run time. so there's no issue with a single function.

Comment: damn, i did not know about that. thanks a lot, man. you should reply with the answer and I'll tick it so everyone can see

Comment: FYI, contrast with [consteval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval).

Comment: Are you asking for what ends up being `const int randomNumber = 9`?

Comment: so consteval is strictly evaluated at compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) functions can be called both at compile time, and run time. Depending on the context that the function is called in, it will be evaluated accordingly. e.g:

```
constexpr int f() { return 42; }

int main()
{
  int a[f()]; // array bounds must be compile time, so f is called at compile time
  int b = f(); // not a constant evaluation context, so called at run-time
}
```

Note that if you want to evaluate the function at compile time, but store it into a variable that you want to change at run-time, you could do:

```
int const x = f(); // compile time calculation
int a = x; // work done, but value of a can be changed at run-time.
```

If you want a function that can *only* be used at run time, then you just use a "plain" function:

```
int f() { return 42; }
```

If you want a function that can *only* be used at compile time, then you can use a [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) function:

```
consteval int f() { return 42; }
```